# READ access to Salesforce Schema through SQL Management Studio or some other IDE

Tags: apex, soql, sqlserver

I'm having problems writing SOQL statements to include a number of different objects and creating temporary fields for adhoc querying.

I'm able to do this with a Standard SQL Server database.  I'm wondering if it's possible to get **READ** access to the schema such that I can write a query to create conditionally calculated fields `sum((if x=='something',1,0)` , perhaps outer-joins, and other complexities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the differences between [SQL and SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/From_SQL_to_SOQL) would limit the usefulness of SQL Server Management Studio. You would probably be better off with a tool that directly builds SOQL.

Some options include:

- [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) SOQL Query

[image]

- [SoqlXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/)

[image]

- [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-SOQL-Queries.aspx) (Disclosure - this is a free tool from my current employer)

If you really want to use SQL Server management studio, you could use the third party like [DBAmp](http://www.forceamp.com/) that will make the Salesforce schema appear as a database that you can query. It doesn't use direct SQL. Instead it translates SQL to SOQL. There is also the [CData ADO.NET Provider](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/salesforce/ado/).